# Text color of TextView doesn't change because of the amount of characters

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableView with textView in each cell.
When the user is 'Pulling to Refresh' the tableView - the function of changing the text color of the textView is implemented.
And it doesn't always work - when the textView contains more than 4 numbers\letters in english - it doesn't change the color, in any other language or if it's less than 4 characters - it works!
My code has nothing to do with limitation of number/letters/more or less charaters.

Looks like this:

**Cell 1:** less than 5 characters.

**Cell 2 & 3:** More than 4 characters & in english.
[image]

**This is my code:**

```
    var colorNumber = 1
    var currentColor = UIColor()
    var refreshControl: UIRefreshControl!

func colors() {
    switch colorNumber {
            case 1: currentColor = UIColor(red: 252/255, green: 244/255, blue: 250/255, alpha: 1)
            case 2: currentColor = UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 200/255, blue: 100/255, alpha: 1)
            default: currentColor = UIColor(red: 100/255, green: 28/255, blue: 37/255, alpha: 1)
    }
            tableView.reloadData()
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! notesTableViewCell
    cell.textView.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.textView.isEditable = false
    cell.textView.isSelectable = false
    cell.textView.text = contentInNotes[indexPath.row]
    cell.textView.textColor = currentColor
    cell.textView.backgroundColor = .clear
}

func refreshColor(sender:AnyObject) {
        switch colorNumber {
        case 1:
            colorNumber = 2
        case 2:
            colorNumber = 3
        case 3:
            colorNumber = 1
        default:
            colorNumber = 1
        }
        colors()
        refreshControl.endRefreshing()
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
        refreshControl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to Change Colors")
        refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refreshColor(sender:)), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
        tableView.addSubview(refreshControl)
    }
```

Comment: what are you trying to do by changing text color?

Comment: @schmidt9 What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Well as you mention in the part of the code that you provide there is no trace of caracter limitations or languages so I don't think your issue is caused by this unless there is another part of your code that you don't show us.

Let's suppose that you don't. You are saying that your pull to refresh and your change of colour is not "always" working. So, there is problable an error in your implementation of your code. Let's navigate through it.

I suppose that `colorNumber` and `currentColor` are global variables for your whole controller. **Meaning that there are potentially modified by multiple functions or logic in your code = possible wrong value = possible wrong color display for your text.**

You initialize `colorNumber = 1` but why did you initialize `currentColor` to `UIColor()`. Based on your logic, I will initialize it with `UIColor(red: 252/255, green: 244/255, blue: 250/255, alpha: 1)` corresponding to the case of colorNumber equals to 1 in your `func colors()`. Then, your reload your table data it seems ok. You are dequeuing your cells it seems also normal. Nothing to say about.

Then in your function `func refreshColor(sender:AnyObject)` you have a switch with **4 possible cases : 1, 2, 3 and default.** For me you only have 3 cases in your function `colors()` with 1, 2 and default. **Why did you add a third case with colorNumber = 3 ?** For me you only need to write this function like this :

```
func refreshColor(sender:AnyObject) {
    switch colorNumber {
    case 1:
        colorNumber = 2
    case 2:
        colorNumber = 3
    default:
        colorNumber = 1
    }
    colors()
    refreshControl.endRefreshing()
}
```

Finally you add in the `viewDidLoad` your refresh control. It seems normal to me. **Try to control the value of your two global variables `colorNumber` and `currentColor`**. Print their value and try to understand how their value are modified in the flow of your code.

*Advice : As you use two switches and basically the same cases, you can create an enum like this : 
`enum TextColor: Int { case black = 0, case red = 1 ... }`
It's more readable and concise and if you want to go further you can associate values withing your enumeration : [Enumerations](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html)*

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, but unfortunately it still doesn't work properly. The switch case of 1,2 & default did help me reduce my code lines.